# Google Cloud Platform instance creation failure (Invalid value for field 'resource.disks[1].initializeParams.diskSizeGb')

Tags: google-cloud-platform, solid-state-drive, nvme

I'm trying to create an instance using GCP. The followings are the specifications (the rest of the settings are set as default):

```
Region: us-west1-b
GPU type: NVIDIA Tesla V100
Number of GPUs: 1
Series: N1
Machine type: Custom (12 vCPUs, 64GB memory)
Booting disk: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS balanced persistent disk 50GB
Add local SSD: 16 NVMes (Each SSD is 375GB, so total of 375GB * 16 = 6000GB)
```

It seems that adding the local SSDs is making problem. The error message says:

```
Invalid value for field 'resource.disks[1].initializeParams.diskSizeGb': '6000'. Invalid local SSD size in GB: 6000
```

However, I don't understand why it is impossible to create this instance. When I googled for the error message, there is not much to tell. Is there any clue what that error message indicates, and how I can fix it?

--Edit--

After reading the comments, I've added and clarified some details on the instance that I've created. Please refer to the details above.

Comment: I'm having the same issue when creating an instance using the web GUI: `Invalid value for field 'resource.disks[1].initializeParams.diskSizeGb': '1500'. Invalid local SSD size in GB: 1500`. I hope this is just a temporary issue and will be fixed soon.

Comment: Can you provide these details: Number of GPUs , series , machine type you have used in creating the VM instance?

Comment: The disk size is 375 GB and not 6000 GB. Your question does not show how you are creating the instance. Include the options that you are specifying for disks.

Comment: @GoliNikitha I've added details in the post.

Comment: @JohnHanley The size of each disk is 375GB, and since I've attempted to add 16 local NVMe SSDs, it will result in 375GB * 16 = 6000GB. The rest of the settings are left as default.

Comment: @PureGero As you've said, this may be a temporary issue. I hope Google Cloud team finds this problem quickly, but I don't know how to reach them. It seems that I have to register a paid plan to reach them out :/

Comment: How are you trying to create an instance from console or using CLI commands ?

Comment: @GoliNikitha I am using the console.

Comment: If the answer was useful, please upvote or mark the answer as accepted for greater visibility for community members.

Comment: @GoliNikitha Sorry for the late feedback. I've successfully created the instance using the CLI command. The actual command that I used, though, was a bit different. I will leave the command that I've used in the below comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround, try creating the VM instance using the CLI command in gcloud.

**`gcloud compute instances create <Instance-name> --project=<Project-id>  --zone=us-west1-b --machine-type=n1-standard-16 --network-interface=network-tier=PREMIUM,subnet=default --maintenance-policy=MIGRATE --service-account=<service-account> --scopes=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform --create-disk=auto-delete=yes,boot=yes,device-name=test-lots-of-ssd,image=projects/ubuntu-os-cloud/global/images/ubuntu-1804-bionic-v20220331a,mode=rw,size=10,type=projects/<project-id> /zones/us-west1-b/diskTypes/pd-balanced --local-ssd=interface=NVME --local-ssd=interface=NVME --local-ssd=interface=NVME --local-ssd=interface=NVME --local-ssd=interface=NVME --local-ssd=interface=NVME --local-ssd=interface=NVME --local-ssd=interface=NVME --local-ssd=interface=NVME --local-ssd=interface=NVME --local-ssd=interface=NVME --local-ssd=interface=NVME --local-ssd=interface=NVME --local-ssd=interface=NVME --local-ssd=interface=NVME --local-ssd=interface=NVME --no-shielded-secure-boot --shielded-vtpm --shielded-integrity-monitoring --reservation-affinity=any`**

**Note:** Replace the values of Instance name,Project ID and Service account in the CLI command and use this command to create an instance in gcloud.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion to use the CLI command instead of the console. I've changed part of your command as followings and it worked: --machine-type=custom-12-65536  --maintenance-policy=TERMINATE --accelerator=count=1,type=nvidia-tesla-v100